# POST to Page Returned By WebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, flickr, httpwebresponse, yahoo-oauth

I am using WebRequest to POST to a signin page that redirects me to the page I really need to post to.

How can I post to this page that I have been redirected to? Here is the Code:

*****NEW STUFF*****

Here is what is happening after I post to the login page:
GET /config/validate?.src=flickr&.pc=5134&.scrumb=6l14Ni2Pz3j&.pd=c%3DE0.GahOp2e4MjkX.5l2HgAoLkpmyPvccpVM-&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fsignin%2Fyahoo%2F%3Fredir%3D%252Fpeople%252Flindieb68%252Frelationship%252F

GET /signin/yahoo/?redir=%2Fpeople%2Flindieb68%2Frelationship%

GET /cookie_check.gne?pass=%2Fpeople%2Flindieb68%2Frelationship%2F&fail=register_cookies.gne

GET /people/lindieb68/relationship/

The last one is where I need to click a button.  Should I just go through all these GETs and collect cookies?  I will try it after dinner and let you know.  I feel like this will work.  I will update in a little bit.

```
        private CookieContainer LoginYahoo(CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            string appURL = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=flickr&.pc=5134&.scrumb=0&.pd=c%3DE0.GahOp2e4MjkX.5l2HgAoLkpmyPvccpVM-&.intl=us&.done=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.com%2Fconfig%2Fvalidate%3F.src%3Dflickr%26.pc%3D5134%26.scrumb%3D0%26.pd%3Dc%253DE0.GahOp2e4MjkX.5l2HgAoLkpmyPvccpVM-%26.intl%3Dus%26.done%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.flickr.com%252Fsignin%252Fyahoo%252F%253Fredir%253D%25252Fpeople%25252Flindieb68%25252Frelationship%25252F&rl=1";
            string strPostData = ".tries=1&.src=flickr&.md5=&.hash=&.js=&.last=&promo=&.intl=us&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=0delt5h5l4df0&.v=0&.challenge=3DZF0DFFqdE0m.9MWnCq6LjUZ9gV&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=1&.chkP=Y&.done=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.com%2Fconfig%2Fvalidate%3F.src%3Dflickr%26.pc%3D5134%26.scrumb%3D0%26.pd%3Dc%253DE0.GahOp2e4MjkX.5l2HgAoLkpmyPvccpVM-%26.intl%3Dus%26.done%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.flickr.com%252Fsignin%252Fyahoo%252F%253Fredir%253D%25252Fpeople%25252Flindieb68%25252Frelationship%25252F&.pd=flickr_ver%3D0%26c%3DE0.GahOp2e4MjkX.5l2HgAoLkpmyPvccpVM-%26ivt%3D%26sg%3D&login=loginName&passwd=Password&.persistent=y&.save=Sign+In";

            // Setup the http request.
            HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(appURL) as
            HttpWebRequest;
            wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            wrWebRequest.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
            wrWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = cookies;
            wrWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; 

            // Post to the login form.
            StreamWriter swRequestWriter = new
            StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
            swRequestWriter.Write(strPostData);
            swRequestWriter.Close();

            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Read the response
            StreamReader srResponseReader = new
            StreamReader(hwrWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string strResponseData = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
            srResponseReader.Close();

            //YOU ARE NOW LOGGED IN TO YAHOO!
            //NEED TO POST AGAIN TO WHAT hwrWebResponse RETURNS
            ShowInBrowser(strResponseData);
            return cookieContainer;
        }
```

Comment: is this more complicated the just calling the code you already have with a different url?

Comment: Yea.  When I do that it tries to make me login again.  Which puts me right back where I started.

Also, AllowAutoRedirect is true.  It redirects me to where I want to go.  I just don't know how to POST something to where it redirects me to.  Like I said it makes me login again if I try to directly access the page.

I login at the url in the code.  I need to click a button at "http://flickr.com/people/lindieb68/relationship/".

This posted code will redirect me to there, but after you login and try to go there it asks for a password again.

I dunno what to do.

Comment: BTW, this is the best website in the world.  Just started using it today.  Its fun to ask and answer questions.  Almost like playing WoW but for programming and getting things done instead of wasting away =D

Comment: so the response you are getting is a page where a human would normally click a button, but you are trying to write code that will mimic that behavior? Are you actually displaying the returned page in a browser (I suppose from the ShowInBrowser function call) or do you want to parse out the returned string and create the same post request that a real user would?

Comment: Create the same post request that a real user would

I was just using ShowBrowser(), which shows the destination in a WebBrowser to see where it was going....Its really a remnant of a previous problem I had.

Im going to collect the cookies and see what happens.  Be back in 20 min or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect all the cookies from the previous (login) responses as at least one of them will be the cookie that tells Yahoo that you have already logged in.  Then include the cookies with your post requst to the destination page, or any other interaction with Yahoo.

**Edit:** See this article for a complete code example for collecting and re-using cookies.
http://blogs.msdn.com/dgorti/archive/2005/08/16/452347.aspx

Comment: When you set autoredirect to true does it collect cookies along its path?  Like if it redirects and then redirects and redirects does it pick up cookies at each stop if there are cookies?  Or do you have to do it manually?  Either way I cant get this thing working.

Comment: Use Fiddler (or some other HTTP debugging proxy) to capture the traffic from a normal login with a browser.  Then confirm that your programmatic requests include the same cookies.

Comment: Can't get it to work, but I imagine that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set AllowAutoRedirect to true on your HttpWebREquest instance.

Comment: I did.  It IS redirecting to the page that I need to click a submit button on.  I just dont know how to post to the page it redirected me to.  It makes me signin again when I try to directly access it.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting complicated.

The short answer seems to be Collect the Cookies.  For some reason I fail at doing it though.